# Use of either/or in maths

Tags: logic, terminology

I have been using these two words for a long time, especially when representing the solutions to quadratic equations. But I am little confused. These terms are often used simultaneously, but it seems that I am confused with the three meanings they imply when they are used simultaneously.

Let me add a few examples to add some clarity:

**First Meaning:**

> *For example when we say, "Boys will go to the Church either tomorrow or the day after tomorrow and blah blah blah"*
>
> *Consider another example: that when someone asks how many oranges are in the basket and we reply, "Either 2 or 3, but they are not sweet".*
>
> *So the first meaning, they simultaneously provide, is that they show choice between two or more things i.e. if the boys will go to the Church then they would go there only tomorrow or if they don't go there tomorrow then they would go there the day after tomorrow i.e., only one option is applicable.*

When we say,

$Either$ $x=2$ $or$ $x=3$

Do we mean that Either (only) $x=2$ or (only) $x=3$?

**Second Meaning:**

> *I have no example for this meaning other than of "Solutions to Quadratics"*
>
> Suppose we say
>
> *Either $x=2$ or $x=-2$*

Then, do we mean that *at a time* Either $x=2$ or $x=-2$? However both are solutions to the given equation.

**Third Meaning:**

> For instance when we say, "Randy studies German on either Tuesday or Friday."
>
> Do we represent our answer using Either/or to minimize the ambiguity that is, whether both be the solutions or only either of them?

If you haven't get me yet then feel easy to post a general answer however a general answer would be of more value.

Comment: Or $x=2=3$? All your different meanings really are the same: _exclusive or_. One of the two statements is true and the other is false. For the quadratic, "either $x=2$ or $x=-2$" is incomplete. The full sentence would be "If $x^2 - 4 = 0$ then either $x=2$ or $x=-2$". These last two equations are mutually exclusive by their nature, since in $\mathbb R$, $2\ne -2$.

Comment: $x$ can only be one number at a time. One possibility is $2$, the other is $-2$. On the other hand, when we talk about "$A$ or $B$ is true", convention dictates that this means that one of { "$A$ is true", "$B$ is true" , "$A$ is true and $B$ is true" } holds. This is in conflict with normal English usage, of course, so it's important to make sure you know which they mean.

Comment: In the English language, both _either/or_ and just a simple _or_ can take on either meaning: inclusive or exclusive disjunction (see the answer below). It's more common to translate exclusive disjunction as _either/or_, but a simple _or_ in English also commonly has this meaning, and _either/or_ can sometimes be inclusive when the _either_ is just added for emphasis. Natural language is, as always, ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are getting at is the difference between the [inclusive disjunction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InclusiveDisjunction.html) and the [exclusive disjunction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExclusiveDisjunction.html).

Suppose you have two arguments, $P$ and $Q$. The following is the truth table for the "inclusive or" often denote by $P\lor Q$:

$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\lor Q \\ \hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & T\\
F & F & F 
\end{array}}
$

The following is the truth table for the "exclusive or," sometimes denoted by $P\,\dot\lor\,Q$ (other notations include $\mathsf{XOR},\oplus,\underline\vee, \dot\vee, \nleftrightarrow, \not\equiv$, etc.):

$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\,\dot\lor\,Q \\ \hline
T & T & F\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & T\\
F & F & F 
\end{array}}
$

As you can see, $P\lor Q$ is true when either $P$ is true or $Q$ is true (**or both**), whereas $P\,\dot\lor\,Q$ is true when either $P$ is true or $Q$ is true (**but not both**).

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: n.b. In computer science and engineering, the latter is often denoted XOR.

Comment: @Arkamis Yes, it seems like there are several notations for the exclusive disjunction--my first encounter was $p\stackrel{.}{\lor}q$, but I think XOR is actually more common. Do you know of any other notations?

Comment: I don't, but I felt it worth commenting for completeness, because this is a very good answer :)

Comment: @Arkamis Appreciate the compliment! I haven't seen alternate notation either--maybe that is a good thing. :)

Comment: A common notation for exclusive disjunction is $\oplus$.  Alternatives such as $\underline\vee, \dot\vee, \nleftrightarrow, \not\equiv$ may also sometimes be encountered.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for letting me know. I've added them to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment rather than an answer.

Suppose you have a quadratic equation, say

$$x^2-x-6=0.$$

To solve this we first *assume* that $x$ is a solution. From this assumption we derive that $x=-2$ or $x=-3$.

So $x$ a solution $\Rightarrow x=-2$ or $x=3$.

Therefore the set of numbers that solve the equation are $\{-2,3\}$ --- and we can say that $-2$ *and* $3$ are solutions.

Our solution technique, assuming $x$ is a solution, can only give us one number at a time but if there 'can be more than one time'.

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly to your question and add to the previous answer, when formalizing a statement such as:

- "the solution for the equation $x^2-1=0$ is either $x=1$ or $x=-1$"

What we are saying formally in Mathematics is (assuming we are working with real numbers):

- "for every real number $x$, if $x$ satisfies that $x^2-1=0$, then $x=1$ or $x=2$"

And completely formalized in first order logic we would get:

- $\forall x[x^2-1=0\Rightarrow (x=1\vee x=-1)]$ (i.e. we are using the inclusive disjunction)

But what does this symbol $\vee$ really means? From the options that you listed the **second meaning** is the one **closest** to it and that's the one you should generally assume when dealing with mathematic statements. Whenever we do not intend that meaning, i.e. we are using the exclusive disjunction, it is common to say "either + or + but not both".

Something similar happens when using "if+then" statements: sometimes we use those kind of statements in every day English to express causality (x causes y) but in Mathematics that is not their meaning. That's why you should take the logical connectives as different kinds of "either+or, and, if+then". I'll allow myself to promote my videos if you want to watch some further examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifvJ8cY1qtM