# Logic notation question

Tags: logic, notation

If I have some statements $P$ and $Q$ and I have the following logic formula: "$P$ or $Q$", does that mean only one of them is true or both of them can be true?

Comment: Either one or both.

Comment: It’s inclusive *or*: at least one of them is true. Thus, both may be true.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254415/use-of-either-or-in-maths/1254440#1254440) for an elaboration on *inclusive* vs. *exclusive* "or." Essentially, $P\lor Q$ is true when either $P$ or $Q$ or both are true when the "or" is used in the *inclusive* sense. On the other hand, $P\lor Q$ is true only when either $P$ or $Q$ is true (not both) when used in the *exclusive* sense.

Comment: The convention is as stated by other comments, at least in formal logic. In computer science, if you want ONLY one statement to be true you use what's called "XOR" instead of "OR".

Comment: Imagine if I ask you "Are you a boy or a girl?" The mathematician would say "yes" to that question - because it is true that you are one, the other, or both.

Comment: By itself “$P\text{ or }Q$” is neither true nor false, so there's nothing implied about $P$ or $Q$. *If* you know that “$P\text{ or }Q$” is true, then at least one among $P$ and $Q$ is true (and conversely). This is by far the most common convention in mathematical logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here as CW in case link provided loses visibility.

---

What you are getting at is the difference between the [inclusive disjunction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InclusiveDisjunction.html) and the [exclusive disjunction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExclusiveDisjunction.html).

Suppose you have two arguments, $P$ and $Q$. The following is the truth table for the "inclusive or" often denote by $P\lor Q$:

$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\lor Q \\ \hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & T\\
F & F & F 
\end{array}}
$

The following is the truth table for the "exclusive or," sometimes denoted by $P\,\dot\lor\,Q$ (other notations include $\mathsf{XOR},\oplus,\underline\vee, \dot\vee, \nleftrightarrow, \not\equiv$, etc.):

$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\,\dot\lor\,Q \\ \hline
T & T & F\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & T\\
F & F & F 
\end{array}}
$

As you can see, $P\lor Q$ is true when either $P$ is true or $Q$ is true (**or both**), whereas $P\,\dot\lor\,Q$ is true when either $P$ is true or $Q$ is true (**but not both**).

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: PS: other symbols for exclusive-or that you might encounter are: $$\dot\vee \;,\, \oplus \;,\, \veebar \;,\, \nleftrightarrow$$

Answer (score 3):

It means that at least one of them is true (so, if both are true, then "P or Q" is also true).

Comment: Only if the "or" being used is in the *inclusive* sense.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow OP asked about "logic formuas", where "or" is inclusive unless otherwise specified. It's true that sometimes natural language usage has "or" be exclusive, but I think that's more misleading than helpful here.

Comment: Perhaps. But if the question is not at all about inclusive/exclusive or, then it seems like a rather poor question (which is probably why it is being downvoted now).

Answer (score 1):

Typically in mathematics, the standard "or" as in p or q, is inclusive. This means that it is true if and only if p and q are not both false. So it will be true if both are true. There are other "ors" that follow different definitions. For example the exclusive or requires that only one can be true.